# Little folding triangles: how can I create collapsible sections on a webpage? 

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, folding

Some webpages have a "turning" triangle control that can collapse submenus. I want the same sort of behavior, but for sections in a form.

Say I had a form that had lender, name, address and city inputs. Some of my site's users are going to need a second set of these fields. I would like to conceal the extra fields for the majority of the users. The ones that need the extra fields should be able to access them with one click. How would I do that?

Comment: Can't help with your problem, I'm afraid, but "Little Folding Triangles" would make a great song title. Sorry, but as a musician it appealed to me!

Comment: maybe because it remembers you this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b1wt3-zpzQ

Comment: What?  Are you playing paper football on the web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I think you mean you want to have collapsible sections on your form.

In short:

1. Put the content you want to collapse in its own DIV, with the CSS property of "display:none" at first
2. Wrap a link (A tag) around the triangle image (or text like "Hide/Show") that runs the JavaScript to toggle the display property.
3. If you want the triangle to "turn" when the section is expanded/shown, you can have the JavaScript swap out the image at the same time.

Here's a better explanation: [How to Create a Collapsible DIV with Javascript and CSS](http://www.harrymaugans.com/2007/03/05/how-to-create-a-collapsible-div-with-javascript-and-css/) [**Update 2013-01-27** the article is no longer available on the Web, you can refer to [the source of this HTML page](https://github.com/toddfoster/lectionary/blob/master/lectionary.html) for an applied example inspired by this article]

Or if you Google search with words like "CSS collapsing sections" or such you will find many other tutorials, including super-fancy ones (e.g. http://xtractpro.com/articles/Animated-Collapsible-Panel.aspx).

Comment: Here's the archived version of the article in question:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120321062336/http://www.harrymaugans.com/2007/03/05/how-to-create-a-collapsible-div-with-javascript-and-css/

Answer (score 1):

Your absolute most basic way of hiding/showing an element using JavaScript is by setting the visibility property of an element.

Given your example imagine you had the following form defined on your page:

```
<form id="form1">
    <fieldset id="lenderInfo">
        <legend>Primary Lender</legend>
        <label for="lenderName">Name</label>
        <input id="lenderName" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label for="lenderAddress">Address</label>
        <input id="lenderAddress" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
    <a href="#" onclick="showElement('secondaryLenderInfo');">Add Lender</a>
    <fieldset id="secondaryLenderInfo" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <legend>Secondary Lender</legend>
        <label for="secondaryLenderName">Name</label>
        <input id="secondaryLenderName" type="text" />
        <br />
        <label for="secondaryLenderAddress">Address</label>
        <input id="secondaryLenderAddress" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

There are two things to note here:

1. The second group of input fields are initially hidden using a little inline css.
2. The "Add Lender" link is calling a JavaScript method which will do all the work for you. When you click that link it will dynamically set the visibility style of that element causing it to show up on the screen.

`showElement()` takes an *element id* as a parameter and looks like this:

```
function showElement(strElem) {
    var oElem = document.getElementById(strElem);

    oElem.style.visibility = "visible";

    return false;
}
```

Almost every JavaScript approach is going to be doing this under the hood, but I would recommend using a framework that hides the implementation details away from you. Take a look at [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), and [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) in order to get a much more polished transition when hiding/showing your elements.

Comment: I am learning more from this site then any of the classes and books that I have taken! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple css only solution that uses a checkbox:

```css
.hideNext:not(:checked)+div {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label for="ch1">More Options</label><input id="ch1" type="checkbox" class="hideNext" />
<div>Whatever you want to hide.</div>
and then more stuff below..
```